# Generate Code pen link programmatically - Javascript

Tags: javascript, codepen

I would like to generate code pen link with pre-filled css data.

How can I do it programmatically in javascript?

I tried posting the pre-filled data to code pen but not able to generate codepen link programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CodePen API for that.

Example:

```
<form action="https://codepen.io/pen/define" method="POST" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value='{"title": "New Pen!", "html": "<div>Hello, World!</div>"}'>

  <input type="submit" value="Create New Pen with Prefilled Data">
</form>
```

More info:

- https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/api/prefill/

Comment: This is used to post our code to codepen , i already using this but what i want is i should be able to get the codepen link(Here i will give the css to codepen ) in my code as a string so i am can use that link as external resource while posting the code to codepen